# Отфильтровать по дате (стрим)

Tags: java, datetime, java-stream

Есть список обьектов, у каждого из них есть поле `ZonedDateTime createdDate` необходимо сделать выборку обьектов за последний год.

```
...
List<CounterReadingsRow> counterReadingsRows = counterReadingsRowRepository.findByCounterReadingsAccount(account);

ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime end = ZonedDateTime.now().minusYears(1);

return counterReadingsRows.stream()
            .map(AbstractAuditingEntity::getCreatedDate)
            .filter(...);
```

Никак не получается в фильтре сделать выборку за последний год.
Может кто подскажет пример. Благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.filter(d -> d.compareTo(end) > 0)
```

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, вам нужно что-то такое

```
return counterReadingsRows.stream()
            .map(AbstractAuditingEntity::getCreatedDate)
            .filter(zonedDateTime -> zonedDateTime.compareTo(now) =< 0 && zonedDateTime.compareTo(end) >= 0);
```

Comment: Andrew Bystrov спасибо!